# Where is Mother Maiamai?

Tags: achievements, zelda-link-between-worlds

I've collected all the baby Maiamais. I went back to Zora's domain and Mother Maiamai was not there. I know she's one of the sages. What am I supposed to do in order to find her?

Answer (score 2):

Mother Maiamai lives in a cave just north of Lake Hylia. You can recognise the cave by its Maiamai-like decorations around the entrance.

You are thinking of the Zora queen

Comment: Side note: You need the bombs to initially open the cave Mother Maiamai lives in.